# Microsoft Azure virtual machine services

Tags: virtual-machine, azure

I am considering signing up with MS Azure. I do not want any fancy cloud stuff, or any of the million other features they're trying to sell me. I just want a single VM with Windows installed on it that lets me log into the GUI and run a program (POV-Ray) at higher speed than on my desktop machine. Does MS Azure offer a service that simple? Also, will they "save" my image for me so I won't have to reinstall everything each time I use the service? Thanks.

Comment: Those are features any decent cloud or non cloud vps provider offers, so I give it for granted that Azure has them. Why don't you just try them out and see whether you like their service? It seems like you already (almost) chose Azure, why would you prefer it over so many other providers without going over the process of trying out a few, or did you do that already?

Comment: I've never used a service like this, and want some info before I give them my credit card number.

Comment: Super User isn't the place you'll get the best answer for this sort of question. If you're trying to get more information on the features/capabilities of a specific provider, you can start with their documentation and the plethora of descriptive articles, or even basic google searches. Forums where open discussion is the main purpose will also be better. Finally, pre-sales support staff for the specific servces can answer any remaining questions.

Comment: Id' like to add two things: 1) Azure is one of the TOP providers of such services, so you can expect they do what you need and more 2) they offer 200$ of free credit for a 30 days trial, and any excess expenses are NOT debited from your credit card. You really have little reason for not trying them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just want a single VM with Windows installed on it that lets me log
>   into the GUI and run a program (POV-Ray) at higher speed than on my
>   desktop machine. Does MS Azure offer a service that simple?

Yes, Azure supports this, you could create your own Windows VMs by using Portal, PowerShell, template,etc. More information about how to create a Windows virtual machine with the Azure portal please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-quick-create-portal).

On Azure, no upfront costs. You only need pay what you need. More information about Azure Price please refer to this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/).

> Also, will they "save" my image for me so I won't have to reinstall
>   everything each time I use the service?

Yes, Azure supports this. You could create a VM image. You could use this image to create multiple VMs. More information please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-capture-image).

Comment: After you shut down and disconnect your VM, does MS charge you to store it for you? I don't think I can upload/download a 128GB image on a regular basis.

Comment: Yes, you only need pay for the VHD cost. For standard storage account, you only need the data you stored. For example, you save 10GB in 30GB VHD, you only pay for the 10GB. Please refer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396917/how-are-vhds-in-azure-storage-charged).

Comment: You don't need pay for the VM cost.

Comment: Hi, please let me know if you would like further assistance. If my answer is helpful, don't forget to accet it.

Comment: "You don't need pay for the VM cost." You mean, storing the VM image is free?

Comment: No, VM and storage are different bill. When VM is stop, you only pay for storage.